# Type hinting vs duck typing

Tags: python, type-hinting

One of the cons of using type hinting in Python is trading beauty of Python code.

Before type hinting my method signatures were concise:

```
def echo(items):
    for i in items:
        print(i)
```

Since my team is using type hinting, I've added type hints to my code as well:

```
def echo(items: Set[str]) -> None:
```

Still quite leggible. After some time other parts of my code that operate on set of sets required my `items` to be hashable, while others did not. So I decided to support `frozenset` as well and now my method looks like:

```
def echo(items: Union[Set[str],Frozenset[str]]) -> None:
```

It started to look like methods in Java, although in Java I could operate on interfaces, ignoring implementation details:

```
void echo(Set<String> items) {
```

Python does not support interface concept, i.e. I cannot state that `Set` implements `Frozenset`. The initial implementation would work both for `Set` and `Frozenset` thanks to duck typing: both behave as set. However, my impression is that explicit type hinting somehow does not play well with duck typing

How can I find a good balance between typing hinting and duck typing?

Comment: I'll let someone else elaborate, but there's at least [`typing.AbstractSet`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.AbstractSet) to solve the interface problem.

Comment: This isn't really an issue with duck typing, which is supported via `Protocol`s. This is just a matter of using an appropriate common ancestor rather than enumerating classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `AbstractSet`:

```
from typing import AbstractSet

def echo(items: AbstractSet[str]) -> None:
    ...
```

Both `Set` and `FrozenSet` inherit (directly or indirectly) from `AbstractSet`:

```
AbstractSet
    |
    |
    +--------------+
    |              |
    |              |
MutableSet        FrozenSet
    |
    |
   Set
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to Python code base where this relation is explicitly implemented? Java JDK contains something like `public class HashSet<T> implements Set<T>`. Looking at `typing.Frozenset` I can only see `FrozenSet = _alias(frozenset, T_co, inst=False)`.

Comment: It's gleaned from the parent classes explicitly documented at https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html.

Answer (score 3):

As said @chpner it's a good option to use built-in types. All abstract types from the typing module are [protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html) starting from Python 3.7.

The conception of Protocols has some similarities with interfaces.

As said in the docs:

> Structural subtyping can be seen as a static equivalent of duck typing, which is well known to Python programmers. Mypy provides support for structural subtyping via protocol classes described below. See [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544) for the detailed specification of protocols and structural subtyping in Python.

Also is possible to define custom protocols:

```
from typing import Iterable
from typing_extensions import Protocol

class SupportsClose(Protocol):
    def close(self) -> None:
       ...  # Empty method body (explicit '...')

class Resource:  # No SupportsClose base class!
    # ... some methods ...

    def close(self) -> None:
       self.resource.release()

def close_all(items: Iterable[SupportsClose]) -> None:
    for item in items:
        item.close()

close_all([Resource(), open('some/file')])  # Okay!
```

While the main purpose of protocols is static analysis they allow to check if the object follows some protocol in runtime as well:

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol, runtime_checkable

@runtime_checkable
class Portable(Protocol):
    handles: int

class Mug:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.handles = 1

mug = Mug()
if isinstance(mug, Portable):
   use(mug.handles)  # Works statically and at runtime
```

Comment: So protocols looks a bit like traits in Rust. I will need to read more on that. Thank you.

Comment: Traits it's not a new concept actually. But they're a little bit different. Go uses structural typing on methods to determine compatibility of a type with an interface. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system

Comment: "The conception of Protocols has some similarities with interfaces." – Not just similarities. They are the same. *Protocols* are a fundamental concept in OO. Remember, the foundation of OO is *messaging*, and networking metaphors permeate OO everywhere. (Alan Kay knew the people who were inventing the Internet at the same time that he was inventing Smalltalk and was very interested in their work. The idea of object == network host, method == hidden local code, field == hidden local storage, message == public API is very obvious in the design of Smalltalk.) In the beginning, the idea of …

Comment: "protocol" was only informal, but it was soon integrated formally into Smalltalk IDEs. Then the first Smalltalk Type Systems were researched, and those, too, were heavily based on ideas of network specifications and network protocols. When Brad Cox and Tom Love put the Smalltalk object model onto C and created Objective-C, they made the idea of protocol part of the language. Objective-C was the main influence on the design of Java, and the `interface` keyword in Java comes *directly* from Objective-C protocols. So, we can draw a straight line from protocols in Smalltalk to interfaces in Java.